# Best way in Java to allow only single reference to object instance

Tags: java, oop

What I want to achieve, say we have an object `jacket` and as we know only single person can use a jacket at time, in code:

```
Jacket jacket = createJacket();

bob.buy(jacket);
bob.useJacket(); // here bob has a reference to jacket

// now let's say bob is selling his jacket

bob.sellJacketTo(alice);

// now how to prevent bob from saving reference to
// jacket instance, because now it is alice jacket and
// only alice can use it
```

The solution that I have right now is to create a "proxy" that will wrap one "physical" jacket:

```
public class Jacket implements Outerwear {
    private String color;
    private int size;

    Jacket(String color, int size) {
        this.color = color;
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public void use() {
        System.out.printf("%s jacket in size %d is warming you right now ;)", color, size);
    }
// ...
}

public class JacketOwnership implements Outerwear {
    private Jacket jacket;

    private JacketOwnership(Jacket jacket) {
        this.jacket = jacket;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        return (jacket != null);
    }

    @Override
    public void use() {
        if (!isValid())
            throw new IllegalStateException("You no longer own the jacket!");

        jacket.use();
    }

    public JacketOwnership takePossession() {
        Jacket tmp = this.jacket;
        this.jacket = null;

        return new JacketOwnership(tmp);
    }

    public static JacketOwnership createJacket(JacketFactory jacketFactory) {
        Jacket jacket = jacketFactory.create();
        return new JacketOwnership(jacket);
    }
}
```

All above classes are in the same package, but they will be used from outside (in other words we may tread package scope like private here):

```
    JacketFactory factory = new JacketFactory(); // crate is package scoped
    JacketOwnership jacket = JacketOwnership.createJacket(factory);

    jacket.use();

    JacketOwnership nowJacketIsMine = jacket.takePossession();
    nowJacketIsMine.use();
```

I feel this solution is a bit overcompilcated is there a simpler/better way?

PS. I don't need to have bulletproof solution - reflection may break it, it just needs to be save from Java language point of view...

Comment: What you are looking for is called "transferable objects" and as far as I know the language, and the jvm, provide no means of having those.

Comment: in the `.sellJacketTo()` method remove the jacket from `bob` by using `this.jacket = null;` and assigning the jacket to `alice`

Comment: You can encapsulate the "jacket" inside their owners and not let the reference escape. I.e. instead of `bob.buy(jacket)` create a `bob.buyNewJacket()` which creates it internally. You can transfer it between bobs easily, since private members are still accessible to members of the same class.

Comment: you can also add a `Person` reference in the `Jacket` class and whenever you reassign a Jacket or change its ownership change the reference to the person `jacket.owner = bob`

Comment: @MikeNakis thanks looks like you understand my problem perfectly, unfortunately there is even no wikipedia entry for "transferable objects" :/

Comment: Hey buddy, do you speak about singleton? Maybe I didn't understand your main idea, but at least you will be sure that only one instance is on runtime.

Comment: @MikitaBerazouski - no this question and solution has nothing to do with singleton

Comment: Singletons are terrible.  Don't use a singleton.

Comment: I read a paper about them some time ago, being theorized as an alternative means for safe multithreading.  I suppose that's what you are after.  It is an interesting idea, I would like to see some support for it, but it seems like we can't have it yet.

Comment: But please keep looking, and if you find something, by all means, post your findings!  C-:=

Comment: This problem cannot be answered because you are using the vague phrase "something about something about something likeish that thingy".  Specifically, define what you mean by "only single person can use a jacket at time".  There are no people in your program.  There will never be people in your program.  There are threads.  Also, define "use a jacket".  Do you want to lock a specific instance of a jacket in a database?  Do you want to make sure that at most one thread is accessing a specific jacket object?  Something else?

Comment: @DwB technical description is in question title - I want enforce that there exists only single reference to given object instance in entire program and that this single reference is not public accessible to any class (like in singleton pattern) but only to the owner. Owner class and only this class may call any methods on owned object. Ownership must be transferable.

Comment: In Java you can never guarantee that there is only one reference to a given object.  The best you can do is wrap the "owned object" in a class of your own that will not duplicate the reference.  Reflection will break that requirement.

Answer (score 2):

what about decoupling all of this?

just have your jacket class, with info regarding jacket itself (color, size, whatever). no method that does business logic.

then your person class, with info regarding person itself (name, age, whatever). no method that does business logic.

then your jacketowner entity, which you can model as you prefer. then you can just have a repo (inventory) of jacketowners and have the constraints as you need (as for example not allowing same jacket to appear twice). in the simplest form, a repo of jacketowners could consist on a

```
HashMap<Jacket, Person>
```

since you decoupled jacket-person and removed business inside the entities, you can easily have a repo of all the "links" and just add constraints on them as a whole as part of a service (where you have your business logic).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is relationship 
OWNER (0-1) <---> (*)JACKET.
My assumption is owner can have zero to many Jackets and Jacket can be owned by maximum one owner.

I propose following simple code. Adding other complexities can restrict unnecessary access to methods (to avoid API misuse) e.g. the transfer needs to be as a single transaction and accessing only set method will spoil the relationship.

```
public class Jacket {
    private Owner owner;
    private int id;
    public Jacket(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Owner getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(Owner owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}

public class Owner {
    private String name;
    private Set<Jacket> jackets = new HashSet<>();;

    public Owner(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void sellJacketTo(Owner buyer) {
        if (jackets.size() > 0) {
            Jacket jacketForSell = new ArrayList<Jacket>(jackets).get(0);
            jackets.remove(jacketForSell);
            jacketForSell.setOwner(null);
            buyer.add(jacketForSell);
        }
    }

    public void add(Jacket jacket) {
        if (jacket.getOwner() == null) {
            this.jackets.add(jacket);
            jacket.setOwner(this);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Jacket j1 = new Jacket(1);
    Jacket j2 = new Jacket(2);
    Jacket j3 = new Jacket(3);

    Owner o1 = new Owner("O1");
    Owner o2 = new Owner("O2");

    o1.add(j1);
    o1.add(j2);
    o2.add(j1);
    o2.add(j3);

    o1.sellJacketTo(o2);

    System.out.println(o1);
    System.out.println(o2);
}
```

Comment: This is not about simple ownership (that was only example) what I need is a mechanism that will allow me to guarantee that there is only *one* reference to the object (like in singleton pattern) but also that this reference may be transfered between objects and previous owner after transfer (even if written by evil programmer) will no be able to access this object again. Yes this is very difficult problem and have something to do with concurrency...

Answer (score -1):

just write sellJacketTo method in this way:

```
void sellJacketTo(Person p){
     p.jacket = this.jacket;
     this.jacket = null;
}
```